# how to call for values inside the last object in xml, using c#

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

This is my xml and I want to get the value of the 
of the last friend(than means only want the `<fname>5</fname>`'s `<streetname></streetname>`). how can I do that. I used XElement with Last(), but it didn't work for me.

```
<start>
 <option>
    <name></name>
    <gender></gender>
    <hometown>
     <street1></street1>
     <street2></street2>
    </hometown>
    <friend>
      <fname>1</fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <address>
       <number></number>
       <streetname></streetname>
      </address>
    </friend>
    <friend>
      <fname>2</fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <address>
       <number></number>
       <streetname></streetname>
      </address>
    </friend>
    <friend>
      <fname>3</fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <address>
       <number></number>
       <streetname></streetname>
      </address>
    </friend>
    <friend>
      <fname>4</fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <address>
       <number></number>
       <streetname></streetname>
      </address>
    </friend>
    <friend>
      <fname>5</fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <address>
       <number></number>
       <streetname></streetname>
      </address>
    </friend>
 </option>
</start>
```

this is my code.

```
XElement rootele = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/CruiseData/cruiseprodutstwo.xml"));
            var getneededData = rootele.Elements("CruiseProduct")
                                .Where(l => l.Element("Location").Value == destination && l.Element("Types").Element("Type").Value == cruisetype);



            foreach (var itm in getneededData)
            {
                d.Add(new Details
                {

                    numberofDays = itm.Element("Itinerary").Element("ItineraryItem").Element("EndDay")//I want it in here
                });

            }
```

Comment: Why didn't it work for you?  Please provide us with the code you've tried.

Comment: done, and I want it while I'm assigning values to the list

Comment: Why `.Last()` didn't work - error exception?

Comment: yes , it says no definition for Last and no extension method for Last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Elements()` instead of singular `Element()`. The latter always return the first matched element without any additional method call, but you want the last here :

```
numberofDays = itm.Elements("Itinerary").Elements("ItineraryItem").Elements("EndDay").Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to extract this value:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
string lastStreetname = xDocument
    .XPathSelectElement("start/option/friend[last()]/address/streetname")
    .Value;
```

Note that your XML is invalid. It should be a closing `</option>` tag in the end of your XML instead of `<option>`.

Comment: I put it for an example, and I want to do it while I'm assign values through foreach, like my code